# Failed npm start because of missing module 'minizlib'

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo

I cloned a react-native project from github to work on, but npm start fails and reads this:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'minizlib'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/tar/lib/pack.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/tar/lib/create.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/tar/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/Extract.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/Api.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/xdl.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/build/exp.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:527:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/tar/lib/pack.js:28:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/yeastbeast/.npm/_logs/2019-07-07T13_59_02_331Z-debug.log
```

Here is the debug log file:

```
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v12.6.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prestart: @
6 info lifecycle @~start: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~start: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/geoffrey/mhs-protect/node_modules/.bin:/home/geoffrey/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~start: CWD: /home/geoffrey/mhs-protect
10 silly lifecycle @~start: Args: [ '-c', 'expo start' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: @ start: `expo start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:203:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /home/geoffrey/mhs-protect
16 verbose Linux 4.18.0-25-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v12.6.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ start: `expo start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have tried installing and reinstalling minizlib, npm, and node, and also a handful of possible solutions found in similar questions here, but have had no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Os: Ubuntu 18.04.2

[link to github repo](https://github.com/hoefler02/mhs-protect)

Edit: 
I'm not quite sure what happened but it does seem to working. I opened the project today to see if anything changed and received some warnings about vulnerabilities. To fix them i reinstalled expo-cli and now all seems to be working correctly.

Comment: Did you do `npm install` first?

Comment: Can you share the log `/home/yeastbeast/.npm/_logs/2019-07-07T13_59_02_331Z-debug.log` or even better the project repo.

Comment: @AbhinavKinagi i did and there was no change

Comment: Please do share the link of react-native github project..

Comment: @AbhinavKinagi it is added now

Comment: Update your post with `package.json` file

Comment: @ravibagul91 package.json is in the github repo

Comment: Do you have `expo-cli` tool installed globally? If not try `npm install expo-cli --global`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `package.json` files contains this,

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "braces": "^2.3.1",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "firebase": "^6.1.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
    "ws": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

`package.json` file don't have entry for `minizlib` package. Also `node_modules` folder don't have `minizlib` folder.

Probably missing to install the same, you can do this,

```
npm install minizlib --save  //here `--save` will create entry into `package.json` file
```

After installing this package you need to restart your app.

Comment: this may have been what fixed my issue, but i had tried this before and it was unsuccessful

Answer (score -1):

`npm install -g npm@latest` (to update npm).

`rm -rf node_modules` (to remove the existing modules).

`npm install` (to re-install the project dependencies).

Comment: Minizlib is listed as one of the packages but npm start still yields the same result